# What should VAGRANT_CWD be set to?

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

What is the default value of VAGRANT_CWD? I set it to something else and now I need to "reset" it. I tried unset, but that won't work because it returns an error saying that the working directory is ~/. (invalid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not be set at first place - if you have this value set in your env, make sure to remove it from where you set it.

The default value is the current directory (`Dir.pwd` in ruby). If you have the variable set, you can try to define the current directory as the default folder

```
export VAGRANT_CWD="./"
```

This will create the `.vagrant` directory along with the Vagrantfile in the current directory you run the command